# How to compare hash containing array but ignoring order inside the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my spec i have the following response structure

```
something: { foo: [{bar: 'baz'}, {one: 'two'}] }
```

I try to compare it but the order inside of foo-array is random.
I've found this article:
[link](http://timjwade.com/2016/08/01/testing-json-apis-with-rspec-composable-matchers.html), and in it, there is the following code:

> Use a_collection_containing_exactly when you have an array, but can’t determine the order of elements
>
> ```
> expected = {
>   "data" => a_collection_containing_exactly(
>     a_hash_including("id" => "1"),
>     a_hash_including("id" => "2")
>   )
> }
> expect(response.parsed_body).to include(expected)
> ```

But it does not work for me as the comparison is seeing matcher `a_collection_containing_exactly` as part of the hash like

```
{"base_matcher"=>{"expected"=>[{bar: 'baz'}, {one: 'two'}]}}
```

What is that I have missed? Is there any better solution?

Edit:
To clarify, here is a minimal reproducible example

```
expected_value = { something: { foo: [{ bar: 'baz' }, { one: 'two' }] }}

expect(response.parsed_body).to eq(expected_value)
```

Comment: You posted code from the article, but how does _your_ RSpec code look like? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @J.Krzus : What is a _hash array_? The copy you posted, contains hashes, but there is no array present.

Comment: @user1934428 I added more code for clarification. But I've found the solution already.

Answer (score 2):

I think the RSpec `match_array` matcher is what you need:

```rb
array_of_hashes = [{bar: "baz"},{one: "two"}]

expect(response.parsed_body[:foo]).to match_array(array_of_hashes)
```

if your top-level hash has many keys, you can write a custom matcher:

```rb
# in spec/matchers/match_sort_indifferent.rb:

require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :match_sort_indifferent do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.keys.each do |key|
      expect(actual[key]).to match_array expected[key]
    end
    expect(expected.keys.length).to eq actual.keys.length
  end
end


# in spec/models/test_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
require 'matchers/match_sort_indifferent'

result = {foo: [{bar: "baz"},{qux: "dak"}]}

describe {
  it {
    expect(result).to match_sort_indifferent({foo: [{qux: "dak"},{bar: "baz"}]})
    expect(result).not_to match_sort_indifferent({foo: [{qux: "sum"},{bar: "baz"}]})
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a great answer but I didn't clarify enough. I want to validate whole response and there is more keys at the level of ':foo' and they are hashes. Checking the array separately would not look too elegant so that's why I'm looking for a way to check it in one match

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I solved the problem with a help of Rspec-json-expectations gem and UnorderedArray

So my solution looks like this:

```
expected_value = { something: { foo: UnorderedArray({ bar: 'baz' }, { one: 'two' }) }}
```

and the matcher

```
expect(response.parsed_body).to include_json expected_value
```

The downside is that it only checks if the expected values are present, and doesn't catch the extra ones.